# Prevent Browser caching password fields

Tags: jsf

How to prevent browser from remembering the password fields ... especially FireFox  ( using jsf 2.0.9 ) I tried  autocomplete= "off" ,still not working , Is there any possibility for this without migrating to jsf 2.2 ?  Am using  "h:inputSecret"

Comment: By default `h:inputSecret` are not supposed to be cached or autocompleted...

Comment: You must show your view code to know what kind of `ìnput` you are using.

Comment: h:inputSecret correct component available in jsf, is there any specific reason behind to use input field.

Comment: @Pushkar Of course , inputSecret is available , but when you use it  one page and save the password in the browser , when you navigate to another page where there is another InputSecret field , the previous values stored in browser are automatically filled without any context and this is a nagging issue eg: you login and store your user name and passsword , you navigate to Payment Page , you can find user name and password stored getting filled up in Cardnumber && Cvv number(inputsecret) .

Answer (score -1):

The **autocomplete** attribute is ignored and therefore not rendered in the output html. I had a similar problem, i wanted to use **placeholder** attribute. I ended up using jquery to accommodate the need

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         document.getElementById("entityForm:searchField").setAttribute('placeholder','Search');
    });
</script>
```

You can use this to set the autocomplete attribute

```
document.getElementById("passwordField").setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
```

Comment: I used the above js to set the autocomplete attribute , stil have the issue in firefox browser

Comment: That has to do with a firefox specific implementation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score -1):

You will never find a way to achieve this, cause the `autocomplete` in this case is happening on the client-side.

You can make it a little more difficult, but at the end of a day it's the users browser which decideds whether to store a password or not. If a user wants to store the password, he can always do it. (A Lot of Browsers are simply ignoring things like `autocomplete="false"`, because its a user decision, nothing the website should decide.)

Answer (score -1):

Hi all thanks fr yur solutions  , Fixed the issue , just made some work around so that code is compatable with both Firefox and Chrome ,

1. Use "p:inputText"(Primefaces Component) instead of "h:inputSecret"

Code :
p:inputText onfocus="validate('Id')"

use javascript to change type to "password" upon focus :

```
function validate(Id){  
document.getElementById(pwd).type = 'password'};
```

then comes the important workaround,adding  tags before and after

```
    <input type="text" name="faketext" id="faketext" style="display:none;"/>
    <input type="password" value=" " name="fakepassword" id="fakepassword" style="display:none;" />

<!-- - After <p:inputText> -->
            <input type="password" value=" " name="fakepassword1" id="fakepassword1" style="display:none;"/>
```

Thus issue Resolved.